# DxDataGrid does not trigger routerLink when keyboard navigation

Tags: angular, devextreme, routerlink, routerlinkactive, dx-data-grid

I am using devextreme data grid. I have the next code:

```
<dx-data-grid #grid [routerLink]="grid.selectedRowKeys.length > 0 ? [grid.instance.getSelectedRowsData()[0].Id] : null" routerLinkActive="highlighted">
```

Whenever I click on a row, it works as expected, but when keyboard navigation (up & down), `selectedRowKeys[]` is updated, but routerLink does not trigger.

I also have problems with routerLinkActive. It does not "highlight" active link.

Refs: 
DxDataGrid: https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/UI_Widgets/dxDataGrid/Methods/?version=14_1#getSelectedRowsData

Router: https://angular.io/guide/router

** If I use routerLink from TS with `onSelectionChanged` event, it does work well, but I don't know how to make use of routerLinkActive from TS

Answer (score 1):

You can try binding it to a property in ts, and update that property in `onSelectionChanged` event.

Comment: Binding what? routerLink?

Comment: Yes like :<dx-data-grid #grid [routerLink]="someProperty"...>

Comment: And do you know what can I do to make routerLinkActive work?

Comment: For example you provided above you can leave it as is. As long as [routerLink] is defined it should work.